# Tool to inject data collected on a spreadsheet into a word doc or PDF

Tags: pdf, ms-word, spreadsheet

Willing to shorten processes and improve effectiveness of an activity, I am looking for a tool that would allow to inject some data collected on a spreadsheet into a document (word/PDF etc).

Basically, the idea behind this process is to give people a certificate for completing a certain course online.
Currently, once they've finished with the course, their get feed into a spreadsheet.
Then, I need to pull this data (firstname, surname and date of completion) into a PDF framework (certificate for completing the class).

Is there a way you could think of to shorten this process? A program/software/script/anything else that would grab the information from the spreadsheet (or from any other repository of the information) and would throw it on the certification template?

Comment: Mind explaining the reason why you've edited and downgraded the question?
Whether this is because it doesn't comply with some rules of the platform or just because something was wrong with the question, it would be great to educate people instead of simply sacking them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed a similar project a few years ago here's the approach I took.

If possible try and get the spreadsheet to come across as a .csv format as it makes the data easier to manipulate. Worst case scenario, convert it yourself, there's a number of examples online.

As for generating the word doc/PDF I'd look at using LaTex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) it is used in Academia to create extremely customization documents and allows for easy manipulation of formatting/design based on imported data. There will be some time spent with this approach but it would allow you to build exactly what you're looking for, goodluck!

Comment: Thanks rdChris, I have had a look into LaTeX this morning and it should do the trick! Very helpful.
I will need to investigate further but it looks like a promising basis.

Comment: hi, can you further guide me on how to proceed, I am a beginner and want to develop a web application, Thank you